# Memory Management: Name that Structure

Tags: opengl, memory-management, data-structures, terminology

I'm working with OpenGL, and using buffers to store vertex data in video memory.  For effiency / convenience, I'm allocating big chunks of video memory, and then reserving chunks as I need them.  There are three data structures I'm using:

- The buffer itself.
- A "chunk" of the buffer - a contiguous block of memory within thebuffer.
- A "skippy chunk" within a regular chunk.  OpenGL lets you interlace your vertex attributes, and these "skippy chunks" let you describe how different attributes are woven together within a chunk / buffer.

Now I reckon that "Buffer" is a good name for that first data structure, but **what are the other two called?**  I assume there's a technical term, but I don't know it, and don't know how to find it...

And here's an example memory layout, to back up my sketchy description (this buffer has three types of attributes: colors, vertices, and normals):

```
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
|c1|c2|c3|c4|c5|v1|n1|v2|n2|v3|n3|
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
|------------Buffer--------------| <- Buffer Class
|----chunk1----|------chunk2-----| <- "Chunk" classes
               |--|  |--|  |--|    <- "Skippy Chunk" class (vertices)
                  |--|  |--|  |--| <- "Skippy Chunk" class (normals)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does the OpenGL documentation call it?

Comment: @cdeszaq: Those are user defines structures and OpenGL itself is not aware of the internal structure of the buffer objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The part with your "skippy chunks" resembles [interleaved arrays](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Arrays).
It is quite common to mix such data (vertices, texture coordinates, normals, colors, ...) in a chunk of linear memory ("buffer") and access it using base addresses, offsets, and strides.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do, but I'm unclear on the terminology. Would "Interleaved Array" refer to an entire "Chunk", with each "Skippy Chunk" being a member (strand? thread? leaf?) _within_ that Interleaved Array, or is each "Skippy Chunk" itself an Interleaved Array?

Comment: I'd say *chunk2* in your example is an interleaved array. How your *buffer* is structured - in other terms, how your memory layout looks, e.g., *N* bytes color c1 to cN, *K* bytes v1,n1 to vN,cN - is completely up to you, and AFAIK there is no special term for this.

Comment: On another note, I think it is more efficient (at least in CUDA) to arrange your vertices one after another, then your normals, then your colors, etc. Your mileage might vary though, so if you run into performance problems do some benchmarks first :)

Comment: I'm using GLSL, and I had _thought_ I'd seen a reference claiming that interleaved was faster.  But then I went looking for a link, and all I could find was [this](http://randevthoughts.blogspot.com/2011/01/opengl-es-and-interleaved-arrays.html), which shows the two to be virtually identical...  I'll have to run some benchmarks, but maybe I'll get to kill that extra layer of complexity - always a good thing.  Cheers!

Comment: And a follow-up, now that I got this working:  My "lite" stress-test shows the two to be exactly equal: 10000 frames in 217 seconds (~46.1 fps) with one-second timer granularity.  Hooray for simpler data structures!

Answer (score 1):

*Buffer Chunk* is actually the most common name for these.